# Problems when using IconAlignment with WinForms ErrorProvider

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ComboBox` that has an associated `ErrorProvider` in the user control it belongs to. When an error happens, I want to display an icon on the left of the combo.

However, no matter what value I set as `IconAlignment` for my combo, the icon gets displayed on the right. Do you guys have any idea what could be wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `Clear()` method of ErrorProvider, it resets the IconAlignment of the associated controls.

You can use ErrorProvider's `SetError(control, String.Empty)` instead to clear the error for the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

in the error provider *itself*, set the **RightToLeft** property to **true**.